# Map [name,value] string values to class without reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, reflection

I'm having a huge performance issue about mapping string property names and string property values to classes using reflection.

My issue now:

```
  public class Person
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { get; set; }

    public string Property4 { get; set; }

    // My class has around 100 properties
    public string Property100 { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping a key value pair collection to the class using reflection

```
[{"Property1": "some value"}, {"Property2": "something else"},{"Property3","Property4","value" }.....{"Property100","val"}]
```

It got to the point that I am now mapping around 10 000 class instances using reflection and the performance is to say it lightly bad.

Any ideas for eliminating the reflection would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide the relevant code

Comment: Do you have control over the data? If so you can use a serializer like json or xml instead of rolling your own. They still use reflection but they perform well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options, if you need to avoid reflection for tasks like this(when code could be programatically generated).

First is

#### Expressions

I use it often, e.g. I saw some people write something like this

```
public class A
{
    public Prop1 ...
    ....
    public Prop100
    public override ToString() => $"{nameof(Prop1)}={Prop1};...";
```

and so for all 100 properties, and always doing this manually.

And with Expression it can be easily automated, you just need to generate Expression for String.Concat and pass list of properties and names there.

For your example, it is not clear what are your data. How do you do lookup in the list?
Let's assume there is a dictionary<string,string>(you can transform your list of tuples to a dictionary), and all properties are strings as well.

Then we would need to generate a list assignment expressions like this
if(data.ContainsKey("Prop1")) result.Prop1 = data["Prop1"];

And the code would be complicated, anyway it would look like this

```
   private static class CompiledDelegate<T>
    {
        public static Action<T, Dictionary<string, string>> initObject;

         static  CompiledDelegate()
        {
            var i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Dictionary<string, string>), "i");
            var v = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "v");

            var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToArray();

            var t = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var contains = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetMethod(nameof(Dictionary<string, string>.ContainsKey));
            var getter = typeof(Dictionary<string, string>).GetProperties().First(x => x.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0);

            var result = new List<Expression>();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
            {
                var cst = Expression.Constant(propertyInfo.Name);

                var assignExpression =

                    Expression.IfThen(Expression.Call(i, contains, cst),
                    Expression.Assign(Expression.PropertyOrField(v, propertyInfo.Name), Expression.MakeIndex(i, getter, new[] { cst })));

                result.Add(assignExpression);
            }




            var block = Expression.Block(result);

            initObject = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, Dictionary<string, string>>>(block, new ParameterExpression[] { v, i }).Compile();
        }
    }
```

It is an example, it would fail if there were non-string properties.

And it could be used like this

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tst = new Test();

        CompiledDelegate<Test>.initObject(tst, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "S3", "Value3" },
            { "S2", "Value2" },
        });

        CompiledDelegate<Test>.initObject(tst, new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "S3", "Value3" },
            { "S1", "Value1" },
        });

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

The second option is, actually, what it should be ideally imlemented like

#### Using source generators

I think such things do have to be done just in build time.

There is a lot of articles on msdn, for instance with samples. But it turned out to be not very easy to implement, even just a sample.

I can say, it didn't work for me, while I tried to do it according to samples.
In order to get it work I had to change TargetFramework to netstandard2.0, do something else...

But after all, when build was green, Visual Studio still showed an error.

Ok, it disappeared after VS restart, but still, that doesn't look very usable.

So, this is a generator, that creates a converter for every class with attribute.
It is again a sample, it doesn't check many things.

```
    [Generator]
public class ConverterGenerator : ISourceGenerator
{
    private static string mytemplate = @"using System.Collections.Generic;
                                        using {2};
                                        namespace GeneratedConverters
                                        {{
                                            public static class {0}Converter
                                            {{
                                                public static {0} Convert(Dictionary<string, string> data)
                                                {{
                                                    var result = new {0}();
                                                    {1}


                                                    return result;
                                                }}
                                            }}
                                        }}";

    public static string GetNamespaceFrom(SyntaxNode s)
    {
        if (s.Parent is NamespaceDeclarationSyntax namespaceDeclarationSyntax)
        {
            return namespaceDeclarationSyntax.Name.ToString();
        }
        if (s.Parent == null)
            return "";

        return GetNamespaceFrom(s.Parent);
    }

    public void Execute(GeneratorExecutionContext context)
    {
        GetMenuComponents(context, context.Compilation);
    }

    private static void GetMenuComponents(GeneratorExecutionContext context, Compilation compilation)
    {
        var allNodes = compilation.SyntaxTrees.SelectMany(s => s.GetRoot().DescendantNodes());
        var allClasses = allNodes.Where(d => d.IsKind(SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration)).OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();

        var classes = allClasses
            .Where(c => c.AttributeLists.SelectMany(a => a.Attributes).Select(a => a.Name).Any(s => s.ToString().Contains("DictionaryConverter")))
            .ToImmutableArray();

        foreach (var item in classes.Distinct().Take(1))
        {
            context.AddSource(item.Identifier.Text + "Converter", String.Format(mytemplate, item.Identifier.Text, SourceText.From(GenerateProperties(item)), GetNamespaceFrom(item)));
        }
    }

    private static string GenerateProperties(ClassDeclarationSyntax s)
    {
        var properties = s.Members.OfType<PropertyDeclarationSyntax>();

        return String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
            properties.Select(p =>
            {
                var name = p.Identifier.Text;
                return $"if(data.ContainsKey(\"{name}\")) result.{name} = data[\"{name}\"];";
            }));
    }

    public void Initialize(GeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t1 = GeneratedConverters.TestConverter.Convert(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "S3", "Value3" },
            { "S2", "Value2" },
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Best performance without reflection would be manual mapping.
It seems your key/value pair collection is regular JSON. So you could use the JSONTextReader from JSON.NET and read the string. Then manually map the JSON properties to the class properties.

Like so:

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonString));

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.Value != null)
    {
        // check reader.Value.ToString() and assign to correct class property

    }
}
```

More info can be found on the JSON.NET website : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadingWritingJSON.htm